# Visual Studio - Navigation bar, intellisense, all gone from some files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am using VS Express for Web 2012.   All settings are as they should be (navigation bar enabled, etc).  All of a sudden last week I lost intellisense on one of my pages.  After trying all the regular solutions to this problem with no success, I tried repairing the installation and even uninstalling and reinstalling and nothing has worked. Not only is intellisense gone, right-click go to definition is greyed out, some menu options on right-click are missing such as "find all references", and the navigation bar is also gone (the dropdowns that show controls on the page as well as the page/control events).  I tried installing VS Community 2015 as well as Express for Web 2015 and the problem persists.  One thing I did notice in the 2015 versions is there is an extra dropdown in the navigation bar that shows the project name.  In all the files where intellisense doesn't work, the project dropdown says "Miscellaneous Files".  In files where everything works as it should, this dropdown shows the name of my project.  So something is amiss.  I didn't change anything so I have no idea what all of a sudden caused this issue.  I have tried to exclude then include files to the project, but this does nothing to solve the issue and it still shows as "Miscellaneous Files".  2012 doesn't have this dropdown so I'm not sure what the issue is there.  I'm at my wits end trying to figure out the problem and have looked everywhere online and am unable to find anything that works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update - I just noticed that everything goes back to normal if I change the master page I use.  My "default" master page causes all the issues described above.  I have another "blank" master page that causes the IDE to work normally

Comment: The issue has been resolved.  Just in case someone runs into this same issue, here is what seemed to cause my problem.  As mentioned, only the pages using a certain master page were being affected.  I was going to delete and recreate the master page to see if this helped.  When I went to copy & paste all the markup, the copy stopped at a certain point.  I ended up deleting the line where the copy stopped, then copying & pasting all into notepad, adding in the deleted line, then pasting it all back onto the master page.  I never actually deleted the file.